# How to vertically extend or fill the screen with custom ExpandedListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have a custom 3 - level `ExpandableListView` with 2 custom `ExpandableListAdapter`.

In the `ParentAdapter` inside `getChildView` I create an instance of `CustomExpandableListView` and setting my `ChildAdapter` to it like this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CustomExpandableListView subObjects = (CustomExpandableListView) convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        subObjects = new CustomExpandableListView(activity);
    }
    ChildAdapter adapter = new ChildAdapter(activity, item, subObjects);
    subObjects.setAdapter(adapter);

    return subObjects;
}
```

**Some screenshots:**

This is what I get when my China regions are hidden:

[image: Collapsed list]

And this one when they are expanded:

[image: Expanded list]

So my `ExpandableListView` takes only part of the screen (I've marked it with red lines), the other stuff dissapear, I have to scroll to get to it. And my list expands vertically only when I add elements to my Lvl 1 (Asia and Europe). I understand why - because they are elements of standart `ExpandableListView`

And I know how to remove upper and left margin - I've set paddings in my layouts.

But how can I force my `CustomExpendableListView` to expand vertically as well?

**Here's my CustomExpendableListView:**

```
public class CustomExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

public CustomExpandableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(990, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

Inside my `activity_main` layout I have only one `RelativeLayout`, width and height are at `match_parent` state.

This is how I initialize my `CustomExpandableListView` in **MainActivity:**

```
RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeContainer);
    list = new CustomExpandableListView(this);
    ParentAdapter adapter = new ParentAdapter(this, objectsLvl1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually I've found some solution.

I've put `ExpandableListView` inside my `RelativeLayout` in `activity_main`.

And changed realization inside **MainActivity:**

```
ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView_Parent);

    if (list != null) {
        ParentAdapter adapter = new ParentAdapter(this, objectsLvl1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is solved my issue, now I have a full screen `ExpandableList`.

But it would be nice if someone tell me what to do if i want to do it through my own `CustomExpandableList`. Because I still have no clue how to do it.